agCharts having 2 doughnuts on the same page next to each other
I am trying to work a little with agCharts to create a doughnut, but I want to use 2 separate doughnuts on the same page, next to each other. But whenever I try to copy the demo code from the following link, it says * function does already exists.
This is the page from where I tried to use the doughnut: https://www.ag-grid.com/charts/javascript/donut-series/
